Cross-correlation of a function with itself
I came up with the following question while writing on my thesis. We assume $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to be a real valued $\mathcal{L}^1$-function. Then the cross-correlation of $f$ with itself is defined as $$(f\star f)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)f(y+x)\mathrm{d}y.$$ Is the resulting function the same as the convolution of $f$ with itself, that is, do we have $(f\star f)(x)=(f\ast f)(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where $$(f\ast f)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)f(x-y)\mathrm{d}y?$$ I did not find an answer to this question online and was not able to show this explicitly (change of variables did not work out well). However, I tested out some example functions and the cross correlation always matched with the convolution. So what is going on here? Any help appreciated.

I think this question gives enough information to arrive at an answer (c.f. your question with the identity posed in the link).

@RollenS.D'Souza So we get $(f\star f)(x)=(f\ast f(-y))(x)$ But does that mean the answer is no in general?

yes, consider $f$ is a (real-valued) odd function.

Thank you very much
